# Slide in menu creating horizontal scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got an issue with a slide-in menu. You can view the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/flobar/Z62t2/

The problem is when the menu is hidden, it creates a horizontal scroll bar. How do I prevent that?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideIn">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slideIn {
    background:red;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -180px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var menu = 0;

$('#slideIn').click(function() {
    if (menu == 0) {
        menu = 1;
        $(this).animate(
            {marginRight: '0px'},200
        );
    } else {
        menu = 0;
        $(this).animate(
            {marginRight: '-180px'},200
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you currently have it, you need to include an `overflow:hidden;` on its wrapper.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z62t2/5/

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body
{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Should help you..

Comment: Cool, I wrapped a wrapper div around it and gave it a overlow-x:hidden and it works. Thanks Prasanna Aarthi

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is helpful for you

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/8nAuk/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z62t2/4/)**

**CSS**

```
#slideIn {
    background:red;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -180px;
     margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: But when the menu is hidden it still creates a scroll bar

Answer (score -1):

Just use CSS http://jsfiddle.net/ZQcaZ/

Transitioning on the width instead of using a negative margin should work fine.

```
#slideIn {
    background:red;
    width: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#slideIn:hover {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but your examples still creates a scroll bar

Comment: @user2575265 - Seems to work just fine in FF, Chrome and even IE9 (without the animation). You must of looked at the link before the "overflow: hidden" was added to the CSS.